# minimax estimator

Tags: mathematical-statistics, estimation, inference, estimators, nonparametric

In the lecture here

https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~yuekai/201b/lec6.pdf

we have

"minimaxity does not imply admissibility: a minimax estimator has the best worst-case performance, but its performance at other parameters may be suboptimal. However, any estimator that dominates a mini- max estimator is also minimax. Thus unique minimax estimators are admissible".

Can somebody explain this? How can one have several mini-max estimators?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose $X \sim \mathcal N(\mu, I)$ is a multivariate normal random variable with dimension $p \ge 3$ and consider the squared-error loss. Then observe the following:

- $X$ is a minimax estimator of $\mu$. This can be seen by observing that it has constant risk and is an appropriate limit of Bayes estimators (in the sense of the Bayes risk converging to the risk of $X$). [See Theorem 2 here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimax_estimator#Least_favorable_distribution).
- $X$ is not admissible because $X$ is dominated by the James-Stein estimator. [See here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James%E2%80%93Stein_estimator). Because it dominates $X$, the James-Stein estimator is also minimax.
- This is possible because the $\sup$ of the risk of the James-Stein estimator *is* indeed the same as the constant risk of $X$, and indeed for most values of $\mu$ (in the sense of Lebesgue measure) the James-Stein estimator and $X$ have virtually identical risk.
- The James-Stein estimator is itself not admissible, being dominated by the positive-part James-Stein estimator. The positive-part James-Stein estimator is also not admissible because it is not an analytic function of $X$.
- In sufficiently high dimensions, one can construct proper-Bayes estimators which dominate $X$. This finally gives us admissible, minimax, estimators of $\mu$ since all Bayes rules are admissible.

Comment: "In sufficiently high dimensions". Why is this a requirement to construct a proper Bayes estimator that is admissible?

Comment: @CowboyTrader it isn't necessary to construct an admissible Bayes estimator; all Bayes estimators are admissible. You need higher dimensions to get an admissible, minimax, Bayes estimator. In dimensions 1 and 2, no Bayes estimator is minimax because $X$ is admissible, minimax, and not a Bayes estimator. After dimension 4, you can build a hierarchical model that mimics the James-Stein estimator but is fully Bayesian, which gives a minimax estimator with a certificate of admissibility. In the remaining dimensions, I'm not aware of any minimax Bayes estimator, but I could be wrong.

Comment: Is it fair to say that one would prefer a minimax bayes estimator when available over a non-minimax bayes estimator?

Comment: @CowboyTrader in general, no. If one is being a "serious" Bayesian, the choice of prior is guided by your state of knowledge, not by the desire to satisfy some Frequentist estimation principles.